# How to interpret "This field is always set to Build#UNKNOWN" for Build.SERIAL

Tags: android

[The official Android document says that "This field is always set to Build#UNKNOWN." for Build.SERIAL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#SERIAL).

[image]

Does this mean Build.SERIAL always returns "unknown"?  If so, it seems to conflict with "A hardware serial number, if available".
Could anyone help clarify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is partly true. That method will return the original serial number on a device if you are running below Android 9 (or targeting a version below Android 9).
On Android 9 and above, you will indeed get the string `unknown` as a result. In this case, the documentation recommends using the [getSerial() method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#getSerial()), which does basically the same, but it requires extra permissions.

Google has explained this in detail [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/04/changes-to-device-identifiers-in.html), the main reason behind this change was that a lot of libraries used these numbers for device fingerprinting. The recommended way to do fingerprinting now is to use the Advertising ID or Instance ID, you can read more about usage of unique identifiers [here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids#best-practices-android-identifiers).

Comment: Thank you for the elucidation.  Did Google forget to add the conditional clause as you used in the answer - "On Android 9 and above".   Their sentence seems to state that something is true unconditionally.

Comment: Well since you are not allowed to submit apps with target SDK less than Android 9 anymore, at this moment it will return unknown for all supported targets, so in that sense it is true. But they could have documented the different implementations based on Android version indeed.

Comment: Weird. An app's targetSdkVersion is 28, but on an Android 4.2 emulator Build.SERIAL returns "EMULATOR28X0X25X0".  Based on analytics, I have the feeling that Android devices earlier than O do return a serial number.

Comment: Yes, that only works backwards. If you try it with say targetSdkVersion 26 on an O device, it will work. But when you increase the version, it will switch to unknown